# Laravel: Adding values from another related table in one query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables that  I am querying (please see the schema below). What I need to do is get the sum of price by the `order_id` which I can get with this query:

```
     public function spendPerCatalogNumber(Collection $orders, array $suppliers): array
     {
        $data = DB::table('ordered_items')
            ->whereIn('order_id', $orders)
            ->whereIn('supplier', $suppliers)
            ->select(
                [
                    'supplier_sku',
                    DB::raw('SUM(price) as cogs'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as qty'),
                    DB::raw('(SUM(price::numeric) / SUM(quantity)) as avg')
                ]
            )
            ->groupBy('supplier_sku')
            ->get();
```

But trying to get the costs (doesn't work and is very messy). For more details, the `costs` to sum are sent from the client in an array like so: `['fees', 'shipping_cost']`

```
        $concatCosts = '';
        if (count($costs) > 0) {
            $concatCosts = array_reduce($costs, function ($carry, $item) {
                return $carry . ($carry ? '+' : '') . $item;
            });
        }

        $orderCosts = '';
        if (count($costs)) {
            $orderCosts = DB::table('orders')
                ->whereIn('id', $orders)
                ->select(
                    'id',
                    DB::raw('sum (' . $concatCosts . ') as costs')
                )
                ->groupBy('id')
                ->get();
        }
```

### Schemas

#### Ordered_items

```
labspend> \d ordered_items;
+----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Column               | Type                           | Modifiers                                                   |
|----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------|
| id                   | integer                        |  not null default nextval('ordered_items_id_seq'::regclass) |
| created_at           | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                             |
| updated_at           | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                             |
| order_id             | integer                        |  not null                                                   |
| bid_id               | integer                        |                                                             |
| quantity             | integer                        |  not null default 1                                         |
| is_returned          | boolean                        |  not null default false                                     |
| is_received          | boolean                        |  not null default false                                     |
| name                 | text                           |                                                             |
| price                | money                          |                                                             |
| fees                 | money                          |                                                             |
| shipment             | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| manufacturer         | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| manufacturer_sku     | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| supplier             | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| supplier_sku         | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| size                 | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| size_unit            | integer                        |                                                             |
| vendor_ref_number    | character varying(255)         |                                                             |
| url                  | text                           |                                                             |
| deleted_at           | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                             |
| quote_request_id     | integer                        |                                                             |
| ordered_item_savings | money                          |                                                             |
+----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Orders

```
labspend> \d orders;
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Column                              | Type                           | Modifiers                                            |
|-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------|
| id                                  | integer                        |  not null default nextval('orders_id_seq'::regclass) |
| created_at                          | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                      |
| updated_at                          | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                      |
| submitter_user_id                   | integer                        |  not null                                            |
| is_hidden_admin                     | boolean                        |  not null default false                              |
| has_invoice                         | boolean                        |  not null default false                              |
| stripe_charge_id                    | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| order_number                        | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| shipping_address_id                 | integer                        |                                                      |
| billing_address_id                  | integer                        |                                                      |
| shipping_method                     | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| shipping_account_number             | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| sales_tax                           | money                          |                                                      |
| shipping_cost                       | money                          |                                                      |
| is_paid                             | boolean                        |  not null default false                              |
| external_email                      | text                           |                                                      |
| owner_type                          | character varying(255)         |  not null default 'App\User'::character varying      |
| owner_id                            | integer                        |                                                      |
| is_manually_purchased               | boolean                        |  not null default false                              |
| is_hidden                           | boolean                        |  not null default false                              |
| manual_date                         | date                           |                                                      |
| manual_total                        | money                          |                                                      |
| po_number                           | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| deleted_at                          | timestamp(0) without time zone |                                                      |
| fees                                | money                          |                                                      |
| three_way_does_invoice_match        | boolean                        |                                                      |
| three_way_invoice_issue             | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| three_way_does_packing_status_match | boolean                        |                                                      |
| three_way_packing_issue             | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| stripe_invoice_id                   | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
| stripe_status                       | character varying(255)         |                                                      |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

To help with the Eloquent query, I did come up with this MySQL query which gives me the correct results:

```
SELECT 
  ordered_items.supplier, 
  sum(orders.fees) as feestotal, 
  sum(orders.shipping_cost) as shippingtotal, 
  sum(orders.sales_tax) as salestaxtotal FROM orders
INNER JOIN 
  ordered_items ON orders.id=ordered_items.order_id 
GROUP By
  ordered_items.supplier 
ORDER BY
  ordered_items.supplier;

+-------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| supplier          | feestotal | shippingtotal | salestaxtotal |
|-------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------|
| Sigma Aldrich     | $715.55   | $725.10       | $309.80       |
| Thomas Scientific | $168.00   | $255.72       | $182.55       |
| VWR               | $800.00   | $259.65       | $377.25       |
+-------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried using `->sum('price')` instead of `->get()` when doing queries?

Comment: I'm new to Laravel and there are plenty of nuances I don't know yet :(

Comment: @fufubrocat I just tried what you suggested and due to the type being 'money', the sum() function doesn't work. This was the work around per a different answer on SO.

Comment: Not sure what `money` does. But usually, the `DECIMAL` column type is used for price. If you don't mind modifying it to `DECIMAL(11,2)`, it will save you the headaches.

Comment: @fufubrocat Yep, agreed on that. Unfortunately, not my decision to make and I don't care either way.

Answer (score 0):

try `sum(fees)+sum(shipping_cost) as costs`

Comment: The costs are dynamic so you may get an empty array or 3 options. Hard coding the costs won't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I actually decided to go see if I could find a solution via a MySQL query (which I posted in my original answer) and that forced me to ask if I can use joins in Eloquent (duh!).

Here is the solution I was looking for:

```
    private function spendPerSupplier(Collection $orders, array $suppliers, array $costs): array
    {
        $concatCosts = '';
        if (count($costs)) {
            $concatCosts = array_reduce($costs, function ($carry, $item) {
                return $carry . ($carry ? '+' : '') . ('orders.' . $item);
            });
        }

        $data = DB::table('ordered_items')
            ->join('orders', 'ordered_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->whereIn('ordered_items.order_id', $orders)
            ->whereIn('ordered_items.supplier', $suppliers)
            ->select(
                'ordered_items.supplier as suppliers',
                DB::raw('SUM(ordered_items.price' . ($concatCosts ? ' + ' . $concatCosts : '') . ') as total'),
            )
            ->groupBy('ordered_items.supplier')
            ->get();
```